# Choose function for objects in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of x number of objects and wish to have a method that takes that ArrayList and produces new `ArrayLists` of size `x-2` that represent all combinations of the objects in the original `ArrayList`.

For example, if I have an `ArrayList` of size 7 I would call this method and it would create ArrayLists that contain all possible combinations of the methods in the original `ArrayList` given the new size constraint.

I know a loop is needed but I'm having trouble with the logic. thanks

Here is what I have so far:

```html
for (Card playerCard: playerHand) {
   ArrayList<Card> FiveCHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
   FiveCHand.add(playerCard);
   for (Card communityCard: communityHand) {
    FiveCHand.add(communityCard);
   }
   Collections.sort(FiveCHand, CardDomainModel.CardRank);
   Hand hand = new Hand(FiveCHand);
   FiveCardHands.add(hand);
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, we're not here to make your homework. If you show us what you've tried so far we can help you with any specific questions you have.

Comment: Graet , we have a programming challenge. But there's any code yet?

Comment: This is a nice little challenge, I wonder if you have any data structures that can do this sorting.Or do you hand-roll one  algorithm yourself?

Comment: @Coffee If you like challenges, check out [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Could you write out an example with an array of size 3 containing the numbers 1, 2 and 3? What would the output look like?

Comment: @Kenney - will do , thanks !!! : )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code; it makes for a much better question.

If you permit me, I'd like to offer some feedback in order to get you to post the solution yourself. For that, we'll need all relevant code.

If you could add enough of the code we need to make a [complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then we know exactly what to change. Knowing what part of the code to post can be hard if you don't know how to solve the problem.
Your code could use some refactoring; this is pointed out by the fact that you never use the iteration variable `playerHand`. So, here are some questions and suggestions, inlined as comments:

```
    // This is enough to make into a separate function. What would it's signature be? 
    // Also, what Class is this in?
    for (Card playerCard: playerHand) {                     // playerhand not used!
        ArrayList<Card> FiveCHand = new ArrayList<Card>();  // better: fiveCHand
        FiveCHand.add(playerCard);                          // playerCard? where from?
        for (Card communityCard: communityHand) {     // there is Collections.addAll()
            FiveCHand.add(communityCard);
        }
        Collections.sort(FiveCHand, CardDomainModel.CardRank);
        Hand hand = new Hand(FiveCHand);     // Why doesn't Hand take care of card list?
        FiveCardHands.add(hand);
    }
```